# Redireccion con php no funciona

Tags: php

Buenas tardes: tengo una pagina en php que recibe como parametro una cadena de datos, me fijo en la cadena y si la estacion es la 13 redirecciona a otra pagina, pero no funciona y no se porque:
Esta es parte del codigo:

```
<?php
include ('funciones.php');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/buenos_aires");
$data_string=$_GET['data'];

$estacion=separar_estacion($cabecera_string);
$fecha=separar_fecha($cabecera_string);
$bateria=separar_bateria($cabecera_string);

if ($estacion==13) {
    $url="http://www.url_otra_pagina.com.ar/datosgprs13.asp?data=".$data_string;    
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
......
```

Me pueden orientar que estoy haciendo mal?
Saludos

Comment: Te muestra algun error?

Comment: si ya mandaste header 200 no puedes enviar una redirección (header 301 o 302, o sus versiones con body 307-308). Son excluyentes

Comment: No me tira ningun error. Voy a probar sacando el header. gracias

Comment: Cuando dices "no funciona", ¿exactamente a qué te refieres?

Comment: A que no redirecciona, ahora saque el header 200 y lo puse asi  header('Location: '.$url,true,301); pero tampoco redirecciona.

Answer (score 1):

En la linea 3 estás mandando

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Como ya estás mandando ahí los headers no puedes hacer un header('Location: xxxx');

Lo que puedes hacer es poner el header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); después del if ($estacion==13), para que en caso de tener que hacer la redirección, no se haya enviado todavia el header.

Buenas tardes: tengo una pagina en php que recibe como parametro una cadena de datos, me fijo en la cadena y si la estacion es la 13 redirecciona a otra pagina, pero no funciona y no se porque: Esta es parte del codigo:

```
<?php
include ('funciones.php');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/buenos_aires");
$data_string=$_GET['data'];

$estacion=separar_estacion($cabecera_string);
$fecha=separar_fecha($cabecera_string);
$bateria=separar_bateria($cabecera_string);

if ($estacion==13) {
    $url="http://www.url_otra_pagina.com.ar/datosgprs13.asp?data=".$data_string;    
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```